# postgresxl failed to acquire conncetion from datanode

Tags: postgres-xl

all.
we are using postgres-xl as our mpp database.
where we excecute a sql throug jdbc,the server will have low probability  to success excecution.
most time,server will response a error,like below:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: pooler: failed to acquire connection from datanode 16416 for thread 140129612068608
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2262) ~[gsjdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1987) ~[gsjdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:348) ~[gsjdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:564) ~[gsjdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:408) ~[gsjdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:288) ~[gsjdbc4.jar:na]
```

pls help.thanks.

Comment: That is not the server responding, that is your DB Connection Pool library reporting the error, and you did not provide any details on the connection pool option or configuration you are using.